# Full navigation zoom in plot in R under Linux

Tags: linux, r, plot

I have problem with zooming into plot after move from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu) in R.
On these data

```
libs <- c('quantmod','zoom')
lapply(libs, require, character.only = T)
getSymbols('NOK',from="2013-01-01") # zde vložit vybraný ticker
data_all<-NOK
dC<-data_all[,4]
```

On Windows I did this

```
plot(dC,type='o')
zm()
```

And I saw an interactive plot where I was allowed to move by H,J,K,L keys. But if I do the same now (on Linux version of R) it doesn't show this interactive plot only allow me to click by mouse but it is not effective.
It shows

> plot(dC,type='o')
>   zm()

```
Fall back to classical interface.

Use X11(type = "Xlib") to enable full navigation.
```

I have tried

```
zm(type="Xlib")
```

or

```
X11(type="Xlib")
```

but it doesn't work.
Any advices how to fix this problem and what is the reason it works on windows but not on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works form me on Linux.
Just do what the message tells you:

```
X11(type = "Xlib")
plot(dC,type='o')
zm()
```

It opens a new device, which allows zooming.

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] zoom_2.0.4     quantmod_0.4-0 TTR_0.22-0     xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-11     Defaults_1.1-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.1        lattice_0.20-29   packrat_0.3.0.104 tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit exhausted and forgot about it.